# basic programming help needed for Firebase, Android

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to this programming and currently I'm trying to pass the value of `editTextName` from `ProfileActivity` to `UpdateActivity` as such:

ProfileActivity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  if (v == buttonNext) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),UpdateActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("EditName", String.valueOf(editTextName));
    userNext();
  }
}
```

UpdateActivity:

```
    editTextName = getIntent().getExtras().get("EditName").toString();
    final DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(editTextName);
```

My purpose is to get the `editTextName` info to `UpdateActivity` just so I could use it to save as the root in **Firebase**, I'm really clueless about what went wrong or what is missing.

Really in need for help as a new user in this field!

Comment: will post up my full codes if needed!

Comment: where is your startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

You can send the value via intent **Extra**, then in the Recipient Activity you need to catch the **Bundle** from the Extra.

To send the data, use Extra:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), UpdateActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EditName", String.valueOf(editTextName));
this.startActivity(intent); // this refer to your Activity context.
```

Then in recipient Activity, you can add the following method at the end of `onCreate()` method:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
   Log.d("RECIPIENT", "No data received here!");
} else {
   String message = extras.getString("EditName");
   // Process the message here.
}
```